# OpenID login no longer working

Tags: google-app-engine, openid

We have 2 AppEngine Python apps which do federated login via the open id api (create_login_url).

We had the login working for some time, but currently receive HTTP 204 on the /_ah/login_redir.

Had there been any recent changes to the flow or API?

Comment: It still working for me. If you haven't changed anything on your side, I would suggest to create a ticket on http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list. Specifying the language you are using and the federated identity. Issue 7975 may be related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some analysis, we found out, that some of the OpenID providers were still working and that the remaining problems were caused by different issues (like changed endpoint urls, or not having a correct registration with the endpoint).

We still have a problem with myspace.com (which is not so important to us for the moment).

Thanks for your help.